# save a object inside an arraylist inside the other class

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi i need help with a personal project. i'm developing a software to manage shows(event), and i have problem to save and object into my arraylist inside class.
i have 3 object, artist,event, contract, every time user sign a contract,between an artist and agent, i want to be able to save the artist  into the agentContract inside the agent class. because i need a list of artist for each agent. My problem is every time i try to save than, my program save all  the artist in the first agent, only. Can someone help me???

this is my artist class:

```
public class Agent extends Person implements Serializable {
float dueAmount;
int percentage;
public static ArrayList<Artist> AgentArtists = new ArrayList<Artist>();

public Agent() 
{
    super();
    dueAmount = 0;
    percentage = 0;
}
```

.....
   .....

```
public static ArrayList<Artist> getAgentArtists() 
{
    return AgentArtists;
}

public void setAgentArtists(Agent age,Artist art) 
{
    age.AgentArtists.add(art);
}
```

---

i'm using this method to sign the contract and save the artist into the artistlist of agent

```
public void SignWithArtist(Artist art, Agent age) 
{
    if (age.getAgentArtists().add(art) == true) 
    {
        System.out.println("\n" + art.getName() + " is signing the contract\n");
        ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);

        for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);
            System.out.print("**");
            ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);
            System.out.print("***");
            ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);
            System.out.print("****");
            ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);
        }

        System.out.println("\nContract signed by " + art.getName());
        ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);

    } else {
        System.out.println("\n*ERROR* Artist not added");
        ProgManage.PauseScreen(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public class Agent extends Person implements Serializable {
  float dueAmount;
  int percentage;
  public ArrayList<Artist> agentArtists;

  public Agent() 
  {
    super();
    agentArtists = new ArrayList<Artist>();
    dueAmount = 0;
    percentage = 0;
  }

  public ArrayList<Artist> getAgentArtists() 
  {
    return agentArtists;
  }

  public void setAgentArtists(Artist art) 
  {
    agentArtists.add(art);
  }
}
```